# How to show a message in the login page if the login fails

Tags: java, playframework-2.5, twirl

I'm using Play Framework 2.5.x in Intellij which I'n not too familiar with and I need to get a page to display an error messages after a failed request.
Currently, when I enter incorrect credentials, the page reloads without displaying an error. I just need a simple way to display the error.

If the user enters their credentials, the if statement evaluates to see if there are form errors. If so, show the form again, otherwise process the submission.

```
if (response.hasErrors()) {
      return ok(create.render(createViewModelForm));
        }
```

**This is the createForm.html in ui\views\sessions**

```
@(gcreateForm: Form[femr.ui.models.sessions.CreateViewModel], errorMessage: java.lang.String)

@import femr.ui.views.html.layouts.main
@import femr.ui.controllers.routes.SessionsController
    @styles = {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("css/login.css")">
    }
@main("Login", styles = styles) {

    @helper.form(action = SessionsController.createPost(), 'class -> "form-signin") {
        <div id="login">
            <h1>Please sign in</h1>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("img/logo_color_sm.png")" />
        </div>
    }
}
```

**This is the createForm in ui\views\sessions**

```
package femr.ui.controllers;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import femr.business.services.core.ISessionService;
import femr.business.services.core.IUserService;
import femr.common.dtos.CurrentUser;
import femr.common.dtos.ServiceResponse;
import femr.data.models.core.IUser;
import femr.ui.models.sessions.CreateViewModel;
import femr.ui.views.html.sessions.create;
import femr.ui.views.html.sessions.editPassword;
import femr.util.calculations.dateUtils;
import femr.util.stringhelpers.StringUtils;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import play.data.Form;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SessionsController extends Controller {

    private final FormFactory formFactory;
    private final ISessionService sessionsService;
    private final IUserService userService;

    @Inject
    public SessionsController(FormFactory formFactory, ISessionService sessionsService, IUserService userService) {

        this.formFactory = formFactory;
        this.sessionsService = sessionsService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public Result createGet() {
        CurrentUser currentUser = sessionsService.retrieveCurrentUserSession();

        final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);

        if (currentUser != null) {
            return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());
        }

        return ok(create.render(createViewModelForm));
    }

    public Result createPost() {

        final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);
        CreateViewModel viewModel = createViewModelForm.bindFromRequest().get();
        ServiceResponse<CurrentUser> response = sessionsService.createSession(viewModel.getEmail(), viewModel.getPassword(), request().remoteAddress());

        if (response.hasErrors()) {
            return ok(create.render(createViewModelForm));
        }else{
            IUser user = userService.retrieveById(response.getResponseObject().getId());
            user.setLastLogin(dateUtils.getCurrentDateTime());
            ServiceResponse<IUser> userResponse = userService.update(user, false);
            if (userResponse.hasErrors()){
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            DateTime start = new DateTime(user.getPasswordCreatedDate());
            DateTime stop = new DateTime(DateTime.now());
            int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(start, stop).getDays();

            if(daysBetween > 60){
                user.setPasswordReset(true);
            }

            if (user.getPasswordReset() == true){
                return editPasswordGet(user);
            }
        }

        return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());

    }

    public Result editPasswordGet(IUser user){

        final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);

        return ok(editPassword.render(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), createViewModelForm, new ArrayList<String>()));
    }

    public Result editPasswordPost(){

        final Form<CreateViewModel> createViewModelForm = formFactory.form(CreateViewModel.class);
        CreateViewModel viewModel = createViewModelForm.bindFromRequest().get();
        CurrentUser currentUser = sessionsService.retrieveCurrentUserSession();
        IUser user = userService.retrieveById(currentUser.getId());
        Boolean isNewPassword = false;

        Pattern hasUppercase = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]");
        Pattern hasNumber = Pattern.compile("\\d");
        ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        if (StringUtils.isNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.getNewPassword()))
            messages.add("password is a required field");
        else
        {
            if(viewModel.getNewPassword().length() < 6)        //AJ Saclayan Password Constraints
                messages.add("password is less than 6 characters");
            if (!hasUppercase.matcher(viewModel.getNewPassword()).find())
                    messages.add("password must have an uppercase");
            if (!hasNumber.matcher(viewModel.getNewPassword()).find())
                    messages.add("password must have a number");
            if(!viewModel.getNewPassword().equals(viewModel.getNewPasswordVerify()))
                messages.add("passwords do not match");
            //check if new password is equal to the old password
            if(userService.checkOldPassword(viewModel.getNewPassword(),userService.retrieveById(currentUser.getId()).getPassword()))
                messages.add("password must not be the same one used before reset");


        }

        if(!messages.isEmpty())
            return ok(editPassword.render(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), createViewModelForm, messages));
        else
        {
            user.setPassword(viewModel.getNewPassword());
            user.setPasswordCreatedDate(DateTime.now());
            user.setPasswordReset(false);
            isNewPassword = true;
        }

        ServiceResponse<IUser> userResponse = userService.update(user, isNewPassword);
        if (userResponse.hasErrors()){
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());
    }

    public Result delete() {
        sessionsService.invalidateCurrentUserSession();

        return redirect(routes.HomeController.index());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily display user feedback by using the [**Flash scope**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaSessionFlash#flash-scope). As the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaSessionFlash#flash-scope) states, the data is kept for only one request, which fits with your requirement of rendering an error message in case of occurring errors.

For example:

```
public static Result yourAction() {
    // Oh snap! Error occurred... 
    flash("error", "Invalid credentials.");
    return redirect("/your-action");
}
```

Then in your Twirl template:

```
@(request: RequestHeader)

@request.flash.get("error").map { msg =>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-error">
    <strong>Error!</strong> @msg
</div>
}
```